# Symfony include static html in template

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

I just started to learn how to use Symfony which i believe is straight forward but i have a little problem with the templating engine. I want to include a static HTML fragment in one of my twig templates in Symfony (`2.5.6`). For now i created a static subfolder inside the resources directory (this might change but it definitely won't be inside the view folder). However i can't get this done, i always end up with an `unable to find template` error. I find the documentation on this subject a bit sparse (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates) also the twig docs can't help me out on this one. I'm not even sure if i can use the magic @Bundle notation or if i have to reside in the view folder as `../` notation is not allowed within the include tag.

I tried the following (and a couple of variations):

```
{{ include('@FashionMediaBundle/Resources/static/pricing.html') }}
```

I guess symfony cannot handle raw html in include but i could use a php template without any template tags as well, so the question is just how to specify a location outside the view folder.

I know of http://github.com/kgilden/KGStaticBundle which will probably solve my issue but i can't believe that is not achievable with the default configuration.

EDIT: i just tried to include a regular template file from the very same directory specifying just the name of the template file (as done in the docs, see link above). Still i get an error also complaining it expects `bundle:section:template.format.engine` as its format. Is there an error in the docs?

Comment: If your bundle is called `FashionMediaBundle` then remove Bundle part, twig namespaced path is called without it, like this: `@FashionMedia`

Comment: @xurshid29 no it's not but you have to omit the `@`. i have a working testcase for another template to include which works like `FashionMediaBundle:Static:include.html.php` but not for `FashionMedia:Static:include.html.php`

Comment: no it's not but [read this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html) :)

Comment: Ah i see. Also works for resources within the views directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the poster found the solution while I was typing.  I guess I'll leave this here for just a bit.

Creating and using twig namespaces is discussed here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

By default, each bundles get's it's own namespace pointing to the views directory.  You can add additional directories by adjusting app/config.yml

```
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../../cerad2/src/Cerad/Bundle/FashionMediaBundle/Resources/static": FashionMedia
```

Load the template with:  '@FashionMedia/pricing.html'

I won't go into all the details but you can also use a compiler pass(http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to add additional paths from inside the bundle itself without having to adjust config.yml:

```
class Pass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $bundleDirAction = $container->getParameter('cerad_api01__bundle_dir') . '/Action';

    $twigFilesystemLoaderDefinition = $container->getDefinition('twig.loader.filesystem');

    $twigFilesystemLoaderDefinition->addMethodCall('addPath', array($bundleDirAction, 'CeradApi01'));        
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{{ include('FashionMediaBundle:Resources:static:pricing.html') }}
```

If you want to put this file in another directory I suggest you to use a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)) (I don't know if Twig can include a file which is not in the `Resources` directory).

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Is your file located at the `FashionMediaBundle/Resources/views/static/pricing.html` path?

Comment: No, as mentioned above it is NOT in the views directory this is the actual complication. I have a testcase `{{ include('FashionMediaBundle:Static:include.html.php') }}` which works a file inside the views directory, but 1) is rendered as twig not php and 2) in the doc they include without the bundle and section but i cannot do that...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know if you can use a file not in the `views``directory. I still suggest you to use a symbolic link if you want to put the file in another directory than `views`.

Comment: The complication here is it might be static content coming from some sort of external source, they cannot have access to the views directory and it needs to be dymanic as far as filenames and count is concerned. Thanks though.

Comment: Thanks once again i found a solution, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

I found the Solution!

In the twig configuration you can set paths and assign a name to them.

```
twig:
    [... twig options here ...]
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../[path to static]": static_pages
```

And then you can include them in

```
 {% include "@static_pages/pricing.html.twig" %}
```